# Symfony assetic stylesheets path to bundle public folder?

Tags: css, symfony, stylesheet, assetic

I read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html)
and [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)

I want to simply include stylesheets with assetic in my template.
**I want to keep all css files in the bundle public dir. Not in any app/ dir from another dir tree.**

My webroot to the bundle CSS tree: `[webroot]/src/Myvendor/MyBundle/Resources/public/css/`

So i took this example

```twig
{# base.html.twig #}
{% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Naturally this did not work with the example path on me, so i tried to insert my path.
I dont want to make use of **@MyvendorMyBundle/Resources/public/js/*** due to the fact of the cssrewrite problems. But making use of this path, the css is going to be taken.

So i tried every relative constellation of my css path. **And no one worked..**

- src/Myvendor/MyBundle/Resources/public/css/*
- src/MyvendorMyBundle/Resources/public/css/*
- Myvendor/MyBundle/Resources/public/css/*
- MyvendorMyBundle/Resources/public/css/*
- MyBundle/Resources/public/css/*
- Resources/public/css/*
- public/css/*
- css/*
- bundles/app/css/*
- bundles/Myvendor/MyBundle/Resources/public/css/*
- bundles/MyvendorMyBundle/Resources/public/css/*
- bundles/MyBundle/Resources/public/css/*
- bundles/Resources/public/css/*
- bundles/public/css/*
- ../public/css/*

I really googled and found only examples that did not work for me, and they seems that they were all in the /app/Resources/foo... but i dont want this, it must stay in the bundle.

What im doing wrong?
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you don't move your stylesheet anywhere it is in `src/Easylearn/QuerybuildBundle/Resources/public/css/`. However, when using relative paths, they are relative to the `web/` directory. So do `../src/Easylearn/QuerybuildBundle/Resources/public/css/`.

I'm not sure actually why you don't set-up a symlink from all `public/` directories in bundles to `web/bundles` (by running `app/console assets:install --symlink`).

Comment: Thanks. I can't upvote your answer, i have not enough repoutation yet, sorry.
Ok now i know that the path is relative to web/ . So i am able find the file.
Ok now i know the usage of app/console assets:install --symlink. Maybe i ran through in some documentations, but did not understand the usage. Unfortunately my OS dont supports symlinks.

Comment: By OS, you mean Windows? It you're running on Windows, you can actually use symlinks, by running the `php bin\console assets:install --symlink` (app\console has been moved to bin\console with Symfony3, but the command remains the same) command within an Administrator command prompt.